# Zend Framework 1 and latester Dojo versions

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, dojo

We are currently using Zend Framework 1 with Dojo forms, and are facing a recent problem with some users reporting bugs while using our forms on IE11: for example they are able to check multiple radio buttons in the same group.
This problem never occurred before, and even most of our users on IE11 don't have any problems.
Also note that no Javascript exception is thrown by the "problematic" browsers.

To fix this, we are trying to upgrade our dojo release version to 1.10 (currently 1.5.2).
The upgrade worked for all the dojo/dijit objects that are instantiated directly in our code (e.g. new dijit.ProgressBar()).
However on the forms using programmatic creation of dijits, the integration doesn't work: the form elements don't have any dojo styling applied, as if the parser had not found them.

We have also checked the most recent release of ZF1, but they don't seem to integrate the latest versions of Dojo.

So are there any changes in the way Dojo parses the pages in recent versions, and that should be modified also in the ZF Dojo library?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, in Dojo 1.5.2 dom attributes were "dojoAttachPoint", "dojoAttachEvent", "dojoType" while in Dojo 1.10 attributes are "data-dojo-attach-point", "data-dojo-attach-event", "data-dojo-type"